# replace a file if different after executing curl call

Tags: linux, bash, shell, curl

Below is what I need to do:

1. I have a url that I need to execute using curl.
2. If the status is 200 then write the response in a temporary file.
3. Now compare this temporary file with another file `("/opt/proc/config/init.txt")`.
4. If the temporary file is different then replace content of `init.txt` with that temporary file.
5. But if status is not 200 then exit with non zero status code with a message.

Below is what I have got. Is there any better or efficient way to do this? Also can this all be done in single line if possible?

```
URL="some_url"
# store the whole response with the status at the end
response=$(curl --silent --write-out "HTTPSTATUS:%{http_code}" -X POST $URL)
# extract the body
new="$(echo "$response" | sed -e 's/HTTPSTATUS\:.*//g')"
# extract the status
status=$(echo "$response" | tr -d '\n' | sed -e 's/.*HTTPSTATUS://')
# print the body
echo "$new"
echo "$new" > /opt/proc/config/temp.txt

if [ "$status" -eq 200  ]; then
    if ! cmp /opt/proc/config/init.txt /opt/proc/config/temp.txt > /dev/null 2>&1
    then
      echo different
      mv /opt/proc/config/temp.txt /opt/proc/config/init.txt
    else
      echo same
    fi
else
  echo "Error [HTTP status: $status]"
  rm /opt/proc/config/temp.txt
  exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Does the remote server support [ETags](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag)? This would let you include the "version" of the resource in your request, and if it hasn't changed, the server can simply confirm that you have the latest version (via a 304 response), rather than send you a duplicate.

Comment: There are several bugs in here related to missing quoting. Consider running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing what it finds.

Comment: ...as for "more efficient", that depends on how large your content is. For short strings, bash built-in string comparisons will be far faster. For long ones, you're probably better off with out-of-process tools. (Also, in general, if you must use a tempfile, use `mktemp` to create them; on modern systems your temporary storage will be on tmpfs, much faster than disk-backed locations; and files created thusly will have unique names, preventing both race-related bugs and deliberate symlink attacks on your system's security).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy fixed quoting issues. thanks for pointing it out. Let me read about mktemp. Never worked before. Do you think you can provide an example with my solution to make it easier for me to understand?

Comment: `tempfile=$(mktemp -t dlContent.XXXXXX)`, for example, will create a temporary file with a random name (random content replacing the `XXXXXX`); on GNU systems, the `-t` tells it to be created in `TMPDIR`, your operating system / account's default location for temporary files; on other platforms, you may need to remove the `-t` and explicitly do something like `tempfile=$(mktemp "${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/dlContent.XXXXXX")`; the `dlContent` static prefix is to make this file distinct from other kinds of temporary files on your system, so you should change it to something meaningful and appropriate.

Comment: cool. apart from that do you see any other issues with my script? Like it can be written in better way.

Comment: Well, yeah. I'd use `curl --fail` and not try to check the status manually at all. As in, `if curl --fail -o "$tempfile" "$url" && ! cmp "$tempfile" "$outfile"; then mv -- "$tempfile" "$outfile"; else rm -f -- "$tempfile"; fi`. And that's if the web server you're using isn't smart enough to be setting an ETag in the headers so you can let *it* do the work of checking if the file changed on its side.

Comment: ...in an ideal world, it shouldn't be your script's job to check for changes client-side at all; why even download content when the server knows that it hasn't changed? (Again, assuming a modern well-configured server that can generate an ETag that will change whenever the content does).

Comment: ...see the [`If-Not-Match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/If-None-Match) header, which can be used to return content only if it's different from a given ETag. If your server doesn't maintain content hashes on its side, it may contain timestamps instead, in which case you could use [`If-Modified-Since`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/If-Modified-Since) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can play with `&&` (when success) and `||` (when fail). For example:

```
curl --silent --write-out "HTTPSTATUS:%{http_code}" -X POST $URL | grep HTTPSTATUS:200 && echo 200 || echo non200
```

and

```
cmp /opt/proc/config/init.txt /opt/proc/config/temp.txt && echo same || echo different
```

Comment: I think you can simplify your solution by using `curl`'s `--fail` flag rather than grepping the response code. It makes it fail on server errors, e.g. HTTP 404, 500, etc.

Comment: @lojza Thanks for your suggestion. In your example I dont see response body is being written to a file? Also if the file is different then I need to move the content to existing file as mentioned in the question.

Comment: For sure you can do `response=$(curl --silent --write-out "HTTPSTATUS:%{http_code}" -X POST $URL); echo $response | grep HTTPSTATUS:200 && (echo 200; echo $response > your_file; mv ...) || echo non200` More you can nested it all. I'm just showing you the direction. Solution is up to you ;-)